# requestFocus() in OnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

The below is the piece of code that i have written for transferring the focus from one edit text to another, but the problem that i got with this implementation is, the focus moves to the particular edit text, and suddenly moves to the next edit text. So, i could not able to enter anything, since the focus is not at all staying that particular edit text ..

```
//some code comes here
// gun_pistolNotes and gun_pistolModel are two diff. editText
......
......
    gun_pistolNotes.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view,int actionId, KeyEvent event){
    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED){
        gun_pistolModel.requestFocus(); // moves to this edittext and suddenly moves to another editext 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
  });

......
......
//some code comes here
```

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to implement any related logic, instead of doing programmatically, you can also do it in your layout file directly, using `android:nextFocusDown` attribute as shown below:

```
...
...
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/gun_pistolNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/gun_pistolModel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/gun_pistolModel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

...
...
```

Comment: I need to implement the logic in the OnEditorActionListener (because i share the code with iOS). so i must instead disconnect from the edit the hability to auto focus to the next edit when the user push the return key and do this myself in the OnEditorActionListener